# Como implementar Find,FindAll, ForEach en iList como List<T>. C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

## Premisa es para un desarrollo en Unity3D con C#

Tengo un clase serializada llamada Tool.

```
namespace Game.Data{

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class Tool 
    {
      public int id;
      public string name;
    }
}
```

Desde otra clase he creado un método para añadir a una lista, ver a continuación.

```
    // type == nombre de la lista genérica
    // data == Tool
    public void Add( string type , object data ) 
    {
        // var insert = dictionary[type] as List<Tool>
        var insert = dictionary [type] as IList; 

        insert.Add (data);

    }
```

Ejecución del script anterior.

```
Tool item = new Tool();
item.id = 0;
item.name = "sierra";

Add( "Tool" , item );
```

dictionary[type] es un **object** que puede convertirse en List< Tool >, pero descubrí que con IList no necesito implementar la variable genérica List< T >  - *es genial porque puedo automatizar mis lista* -  y ejecutar la metodo Add;

## Mi objetivo es crear una interface o hacer de algún modo los métodos de Find, FindAll, ForEach de List< T > en iList.

*Adjunto al texto el método para crear un diccionario con lista dinámica.*

```
public List<TypeItem> types; // Tipos de items
public List<Tool>     tools 

// Diccionario dinámico
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary;

void DynamicList()
{
    dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> ();

    // Añadir listas al diccionario
    dictionary.Add("Tool", tools);  
    dictionary.Add("Type", types);      

}
```

Comment: Perdona, pero he leido tu pregunta varias veces y no entiendo todavía que intentas conseguir ni que problemas tienes. Me suena a que intentas algo asi como implementar [Genericos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/),pero no lo tengo muy claro

Comment: En la interface de iList no tiene los métodos de Find, FindAll y ForEach en cambio List<T> si dispone de ello. Pero con iList si puedo hacer Add, Remove, y RemoveAt como List<T>.

Quiero hacer convertir mi object en iList o en otra interface sin especificar el genérico.

Comment: `iList` no implementa esos métodos porque es un interface. La forma normal de funcionar sería, cuando quieras usar uno de esos métodos castear al `List<T>` correspondiente. Pero, igual es culpa mia, sigo sin entender que problema tratas de resolver. No se que quieres decir con `DynamicList`, ni con _implementar la variable genérica_. Esto se suele conocer como el [Problema XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Resumiendo, puedes explicar de manera sencilla que problema tienes? y si es con un [MCVE],mucho mejor

Comment: Se puede castear usando Type.GetType("Game.Data.Tool")?

Algo que quede así List<Type.GetType("Game.Data.Tool")>.

Comment: Lo de la DynamicList es para tener todas mis List<T> agrupada en un Dictionary, y después mediante un String(Key) recuperar la lista que necesite.

Comment: Vale,ahora creo que entiendo algo mejor lo que quieres. A ver si puedo darte una respuesta

Comment: O poder hacer esto:

dictionary [type].GetType().GetMethod("FindAll").Invoke(dictionary [type], null)

Pero FindAll requiere de un Predicate y no se como implementarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo siento, pero mi respuesta va a ir encaminada a convencerte de que lo que intentas es una mala idea. Si entiendo al fin lo que quieres conseguir, se trata de tener un `Dictionary<string,object>` donde almacenar todas tus listas de diferentes tipos con una clave. Yo desaconsejo hacerlo, ya que es incómodo de manejar y es bastante probable que te de problemas en algún momento. C# es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado y evita este tipo de cosas.

El problema es que con C# no se puede realizar un `Cast` a un tipo conocido en tiempo de ejecución. Es decir, en tu caso, teniendo una variable de tipo `string` con el nombre del tipo (Tool por ejemplo)  no es posible cambiar un objeto de tipo `IList<object>` a un `List<Tool>`.

Usando `Convert.ChangeType` puedes cambiar el tipo a otro, pero como el compilador no es capaz de inferir el tipo, tampoco podrás tener acceso a los métodos específicos de la clase `List`.

Preguntas en tus comentarios:

> Poder hacer esto:dictionary [type].GetType().GetMethod("FindAll").Invoke(dictionary [type], null).Pero FindAll requiere de un Predicate y no se como implementarlo.

El problema es que el predicado va al final a necesitar acceder al tipo subyacente de la lista (por ejemplo, tomamos esta lambda: `x=>x.id==1`. Como sabe el compilador que `x` tiene una propiedad `id` si no conoce el tipo??)

Resumiendo, tal vez podrías implementar lo que quieres con mucho trabajo, pero es algo que no tiene mucho sentido. Al final practicamente cualquier solución se va a basar en `Reflection`, lo cual no es muy aconsejable.

La única solución sencilla que veo es tener algun tipo de `switch` que al final haga el `Cast` correcto:

```
string tipo = "Tool";

var listatool = dictionary[tipo] as System.Collections.IList;
switch (tipo)
{
    case "Tool":
          ((List<Tool>)listatool).Find(x => x.id == 1);
           break;
    //case "OtroTipo":
    //     ((List<OtroTipo>)listatool).Find(x => x.propiedad == 1);
    //     break;
```

Comment: Si todo me lleva a la misma respuesta del uso del switch. 

Es una pena que no pueda usar tipo dynamic en unity.
Gracias.